# Можно ли выполнить onClick метод для кнопки, используя url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли сгенерировать url, при переходе по которому выполняется метод onClick для кнопки?

Comment: Вам нужно, что бы открытии сайта выполнялось нажатие на кнопку?

Comment: @Yuri да, именно

Comment: Можно с помощью Jquery это осуществить. Написать в ответе, как с помощью Juqery?

Comment: Да, буду благодарен

Comment: @Schepalin Можете переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы он был ясней?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, спасибо, вопрос задал по глупости, уже во всем разобрался

Comment: @Schepalin Если вы считаете ваш вопрос и ответы к нему абсолютно бесполезными для всех людей, то удалите его. Если нет, то отредактируйте его, потому что суть вопроса неясна.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() { // код, который выполняется при загрузке страницы
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert('Нажали :)');
  });
  $('button').click(); // собственно само нажатие
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Кликни на меня :)</button>
```

Comment: @Schepalin Если этот ответ вам помог, то отметьте его как принятый.